# Why Quartz can`t find CamelContext?

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz

I have a simple `Springboot` application using `Camel` and `Quartz`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.14</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I set up a connection to the DB:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schedule_module
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1111
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
```

And wrote the simplest route:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("quartz://simpleRouterScheduler?trigger.repeatInterval=5000")
                .routeId("SimpleRouter")
                .log("SimpleRouter Hello");
    }
}
```

When the application is launched for the first time, the route is launched and its schedule is stored in the database:

```
2023-07-31 10:49:08.940  INFO 4744 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : Starting ScheduleApp03Application using Java 17.0.6 on DESKTOP-6SHGJTA with PID 4744 (C:\work\dev\testsapps\camel\schedule-app03\target\classes started by baa in C:\work\dev\testsapps\camel\schedule-app03)
2023-07-31 10:49:08.942  INFO 4744 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-31 10:49:10.309  INFO 4744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-31 10:49:10.468  INFO 4744 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-31 10:49:10.498  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 7.15.0 by Redgate
2023-07-31 10:49:10.499  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schedule_module01 (PostgreSQL 9.6)
2023-07-31 10:49:10.536  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.015s)
2023-07-31 10:49:10.549  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2023-07-31 10:49:10.584  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": << Empty Schema >>
2023-07-31 10:49:10.603  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "1 - Init DB"
2023-07-31 10:49:10.768  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "2 - Insert DB"
2023-07-31 10:49:10.774  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "public", now at version v2 (execution time 00:00.194s)
2023-07-31 10:49:10.889  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2023-07-31 10:49:10.905  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2023-07-31 10:49:10.905  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2023-07-31 10:49:10.908  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2023-07-31 10:49:10.910  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2023-07-31 10:49:10.911  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

2023-07-31 10:49:10.911  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2023-07-31 10:49:10.911  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-07-31 10:49:10.911  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@55f4887d
2023-07-31 10:49:10.961  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2023-07-31 10:49:10.982  INFO 4744 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2023-07-31 10:49:11.136  INFO 4744 --- [           main] .c.i.e.DefaultAutowiredLifecycleStrategy : Autowired property: scheduler on component: quartz as exactly one instance of type: org.quartz.Scheduler (org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler) found in the registry
2023-07-31 10:49:11.186  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.20.6 (camel-1) is starting
2023-07-31 10:49:11.225  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camel-1.simpleRouterScheduler (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is 2023-07-31T10:49:11.693+0300
2023-07-31 10:49:11.237  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:1)
2023-07-31 10:49:11.237  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started SimpleRouter (quartz://simpleRouterScheduler)
2023-07-31 10:49:11.237  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.20.6 (camel-1) started in 242ms (build:51ms init:141ms start:50ms)
2023-07-31 10:49:11.240  INFO 4744 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : The Quartz scheduler: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@315c081 has already been started
2023-07-31 10:49:11.244  INFO 4744 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : Started ScheduleApp03Application in 2.641 seconds (JVM running for 2.994)
2023-07-31 10:49:11.709  INFO 4744 --- [eduler_Worker-1] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
2023-07-31 10:49:16.698  INFO 4744 --- [eduler_Worker-2] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
2023-07-31 10:49:21.700  INFO 4744 --- [eduler_Worker-3] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
```

But when I stop the application and restart it, I get the following message:

```
2023-07-31 10:51:04.883  INFO 21732 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : Starting ScheduleApp03Application using Java 17.0.6 on DESKTOP-6SHGJTA with PID 21732 (C:\work\dev\testsapps\camel\schedule-app03\target\classes started by baa in C:\work\dev\testsapps\camel\schedule-app03)
2023-07-31 10:51:04.885  INFO 21732 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-31 10:51:06.040  INFO 21732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-31 10:51:06.168  INFO 21732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.209  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 7.15.0 by Redgate
2023-07-31 10:51:06.210  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schedule_module01 (PostgreSQL 9.6)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.251  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.022s)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.260  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 2
2023-07-31 10:51:06.261  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.375  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2023-07-31 10:51:06.385  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2023-07-31 10:51:06.385  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.388  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2023-07-31 10:51:06.391  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.392  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

2023-07-31 10:51:06.392  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.392  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-07-31 10:51:06.393  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@93824eb
2023-07-31 10:51:06.433  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2023-07-31 10:51:06.450  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: detected 1 failed or restarted instances.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.451  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "NON_CLUSTERED"'s failed in-progress jobs.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.458  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: ......Freed 1 acquired trigger(s).
2023-07-31 10:51:06.459  INFO 21732 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2023-07-31 10:51:06.530 ERROR 21732 --- [eduler_Worker-1] o.a.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob      : Failed to execute CamelJob.

org.quartz.JobExecutionException: No CamelContext could be found with name: camel-1
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.getCamelContext(CamelJob.java:103) ~[camel-quartz-3.20.6.jar:3.20.6]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:60) ~[camel-quartz-3.20.6.jar:3.20.6]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]

2023-07-31 10:51:06.531  INFO 21732 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell              : Job Camel_camel-1.simpleRouterScheduler threw a JobExecutionException: 

org.quartz.JobExecutionException: No CamelContext could be found with name: camel-1
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.getCamelContext(CamelJob.java:103) ~[camel-quartz-3.20.6.jar:3.20.6]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:60) ~[camel-quartz-3.20.6.jar:3.20.6]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]

2023-07-31 10:51:06.615  INFO 21732 --- [           main] .c.i.e.DefaultAutowiredLifecycleStrategy : Autowired property: scheduler on component: quartz as exactly one instance of type: org.quartz.Scheduler (org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler) found in the registry
2023-07-31 10:51:06.654  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.20.6 (camel-1) is starting
2023-07-31 10:51:06.663  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job Camel_camel-1.simpleRouterScheduler (cron=null, triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is null
2023-07-31 10:51:06.672  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:1)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.672  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started SimpleRouter (quartz://simpleRouterScheduler)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.672  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.20.6 (camel-1) started in 192ms (build:39ms init:136ms start:17ms)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.673  INFO 21732 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : The Quartz scheduler: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@7e8279e5 has already been started
2023-07-31 10:51:06.677  INFO 21732 --- [           main] r.s.n.p.s.ScheduleApp03Application       : Started ScheduleApp03Application in 2.087 seconds (JVM running for 2.392)
2023-07-31 10:51:06.705  INFO 21732 --- [eduler_Worker-4] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
2023-07-31 10:51:11.699  INFO 21732 --- [eduler_Worker-5] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
2023-07-31 10:51:16.704  INFO 21732 --- [eduler_Worker-6] SimpleRouter                             : SimpleRouter Hello
```

Do I understand correctly that `Quartz` cannot find the `CamelContext`, from which it received data about the route and its schedule for the 1st time?

How can I set up `Camel`, so that `Camel` and `Quartz` can negotiate the same context each time they start?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `spring-boot-starter-quartz` starts the scheduler by default. It does that before Camel's Quartz component is configured and `CamelContext` is passed to the scheduler instance context.

I did not find that mentioned explicitly in the docs but the thing is that you should let Camel control the scheduler's lifecycle. In order to achieve that, please disable the autostartup of the scheduler by setting the following property

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    auto-startup: false
```